# How do I use Slurm to run Python parallel program using concurrent.futures?

Tags: python, pool, slurm, concurrent.futures

I want to use the hpc to run my code, so I ran `test.py` using the `concurrent.futures` module. I have 3 nodes, each node have 24 cores and each core have two threads. I want to run the 72 cores (144 threads) once, but my code run 144 times.

`test.py`:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time


def do_something(seconds=1):
    print(f'Sleeping {seconds} second(s)')
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return f"Done Sleeping... {seconds}"


start = time.perf_counter()

secs = [2]*48
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    reaults = executor.map(do_something, secs)
    for reault in reaults:
        print(reault)

end = time.perf_counter()

print(f'Finished in {round (end - start,2)} second(s)')
```

The `jobs.sh` that is submitted to the hpc:

```sh
sbatch -N 3 -n 72 python3 test.py
```

I run it with the command `sbatch -N 3 ./job.sh`.

The result is 48 lines showing "Sleeping 2 seconds", repeated 144 times.

I also tried another `job.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=mpi4py-test
#SBATCH --nodes=3
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=72

python3 test.py
```

I run it using `sbatch -N 3 ./job.sh`
However, I get the output:

```
sbatch: Warning: can't run 1 processes on 3 nodes, setting nnodes to 1
sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Requested node configuration is not available
```

How do I use the 72 cores together to run my one task?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your python script literally tells python to run function 48 times, one time for each item in secs. Why did you expect it to show message once?
2. Slurm runs this script *at least once on each node*.
3. ProcessPoolExecutor() supports max_workers parameter, better adjust it to your problem
4. `--cpus-per-task=72` perhaps may be useless with python, because it is a *per-process* limit, but python process just can't use >1 cores because of GIL, and I'm not sure how slurm counts child processes.

So, if you want to use all 3 nodes, all 72 CPUs in a single job, it may be easier to delegate resource management to slurm entirely. Try to decompose your task, to have one small action in your python script

```py
import sys, time

def do_something(seconds=1):
    print(f'Sleeping {seconds} second(s)')
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return f"Done Sleeping... {seconds}"

jobs = sys.argv[1:]

for job in jobs:
    do_something(int(job))
```

And do the rest in `job.sh`

Comment: Hi, sorry. I did't express my meaning exactly. I want my code to print 48 lines "Sleeping ..." with using 72 cores, so each line was related with one core or more, the total time is no more than 2 seconds. but Now is that each core prints 48 lines itself, and repeat 72 times. The total time is 2*48 = 96 seconds >> 2 seconds. So  I want to use full of the core to run only one task, not repeat 72 times